# Hacer responsive un circulo usando absolute

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

¿Me comparten algo de su experiencia para que un elemento (circulo creado con CSS) se haga responsive?

Básicamente me gustaría lograr algo así ....

[image]

Pero lo que consigo es algo así, y si reduzco el navegador, el Circulo (El circulo amarillo grande) no se hace pequeño junto a su contenedor.

La verdad no se si es correcto crear los elementos con CSS o hacer el diseño SVG y solo insertarlo en el HTML.

[image]

Aquí el código HTML..

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav
    class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light px-md-4 animated"
    id="navBar"
  >
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"
        ><img
          class="mr-2"
          src="../../../assets/bootstrap-solid.svg"
          width="30"
          height="30"
          alt="logotipo"
        />Juan Carlos</a
      >
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler navTrigger"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbar"
        aria-controls="navbar"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navTrigger"> <i></i><i></i><i></i> </span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse FondoDeLista" id="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Acerca de mí</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicios</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portafolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="" id="Presentacion">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="d-none d-md-block circulo"></div>
      <div class="col-12 BarraEnBlanco"></div>
      <div class="col-6 p-5">
        <div class="">
          <h4 class="">Hi There!</h4>
          <h2 class="">I'm Web Developer</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio
            explicabo est voluptates, nam nostrum quaerat tenetur, qui iste
            architecto adipisci saepe excepturi nisi. Ea dicta atque temporibus
            natus minima tempore.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 cont">
        <div class="relav">
          <div class="circulo"></div>
          <div class="circulo"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12" id="home">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<footer>
  <div class="container"></div>
</footer>
```

Aquí el CSS

```css
/* CSS Para efectos */
/* PARA UN DIV SIN NADA */
.BarraEnBlanco {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

/* CAMBIAR EL FONDO DEL CONTENEDOR DE UL-LI-A DURANTE EL TAMAÑO DE SM */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .FondoDeLista {
    background: #282747;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
}

/* HEADER */
#header {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
#header .navbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: top 0.7s;
  z-index: 1;
}
#header .navbar-brand {
  color: #292e44;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#header .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  color: #292e44;
  padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#header .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover,
#header .navbar-nav .nav-item:hover {
  background: #282747;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.navbar-toggler {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  border: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
.navbar-toggler {
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 0.3;
}

.navTrigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.navTrigger i {
  background-color: #292e44;
  border-radius: 2px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
}
.navTrigger i:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: outT 0.8s backwards;
  animation: outT 0.8s backwards;
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
.navTrigger i:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 5px 0;
  -webkit-animation: outM 0.8s backwards;
  animation: outM 0.8s backwards;
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
.navTrigger i:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: outBtm 0.8s backwards;
  animation: outBtm 0.8s backwards;
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
.navTrigger.active i:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: inT 0.8s forwards;
  animation: inT 0.8s forwards;
}
.navTrigger.active i:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: inM 0.8s forwards;
  animation: inM 0.8s forwards;
}
.navTrigger.active i:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: inBtm 0.8s forwards;
  animation: inBtm 0.8s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes inM {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes inM {
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes outM {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes outM {
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes inT {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}
@keyframes inT {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes outT {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}
@keyframes outT {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes inBtm {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}
@keyframes inBtm {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes outBtm {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}
@keyframes outBtm {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}

/* CAMBIOS EN TAMAÑO SM */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #header .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
  }

  #header .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover,
  #header .navbar-nav .nav-item:hover {
    background: #adadb7;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
}

/* APARTADO DE PRESENTACIÓN */
#Presentacion {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  color: #292e44;
}

#Banner {
  width: 470px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6em;
}
#Presentacion #Banner h4 {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
#Presentacion #Banner h2 {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
#Presentacion #Banner p {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.cont {
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.relav {
  position: relative;
}
#Presentacion .circulo:nth-child(1) {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -150px;
  left: -150px;
  background: #fdc801;
}
#Presentacion .row .cont .relav .circulo:nth-child(1) {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #fdc801;
}
#Presentacion .row .cont .relav .circulo:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #282747;
}

#home {
  min-width: 209px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que los elementos tengan un tamaño relativo, ya sea a su contenedor o a otra referencia, se necesitan usar unidades relativas. En tu caso, el círculo uno tiene un tamaño fijo de 300px, los pixeles son una unidad absoluta, medirá 300px independientemente de cualquier otro elemento.

En el ejemplo que adjunto, cambié los tamaños por una unidad relativa al ancho de la ventana, vw:

```
 width: 50vw;
 height: 50vw;
```

Otras propiedades como la posición `top`, `left`, pueden ser también definidas como unidades relativas.

Una lista de unidades relativas más utilizadas:

- `%` En relación al tamaño del contenedor (sólo para anchos, para altos hay excepciones)
- `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax` En relación al viewport
- `em` En relación al tamaño de la tipografía

```css
/* CSS Para efectos */
/* PARA UN DIV SIN NADA */
.BarraEnBlanco {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

/* CAMBIAR EL FONDO DEL CONTENEDOR DE UL-LI-A DURANTE EL TAMAÑO DE SM */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .FondoDeLista {
    background: #282747;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
}

/* HEADER */
#header {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
#header .navbar {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: top 0.7s;
  z-index: 1;
}
#header .navbar-brand {
  color: #292e44;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#header .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  color: #292e44;
  padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#header .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover,
#header .navbar-nav .nav-item:hover {
  background: #282747;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.navbar-toggler {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  border: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
.navbar-toggler {
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 0.3;
}

.navTrigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.navTrigger i {
  background-color: #292e44;
  border-radius: 2px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
}
.navTrigger i:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: outT 0.8s backwards;
  animation: outT 0.8s backwards;
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
.navTrigger i:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 5px 0;
  -webkit-animation: outM 0.8s backwards;
  animation: outM 0.8s backwards;
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
.navTrigger i:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: outBtm 0.8s backwards;
  animation: outBtm 0.8s backwards;
  -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
.navTrigger.active i:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: inT 0.8s forwards;
  animation: inT 0.8s forwards;
}
.navTrigger.active i:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: inM 0.8s forwards;
  animation: inM 0.8s forwards;
}
.navTrigger.active i:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: inBtm 0.8s forwards;
  animation: inBtm 0.8s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes inM {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes inM {
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes outM {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@keyframes outM {
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes inT {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}
@keyframes inT {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes outT {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}
@keyframes outT {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes inBtm {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}
@keyframes inBtm {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes outBtm {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}
@keyframes outBtm {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(135deg);
  }
}

/* CAMBIOS EN TAMAÑO SM */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #header .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
  }

  #header .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover,
  #header .navbar-nav .nav-item:hover {
    background: #adadb7;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
}

/* APARTADO DE PRESENTACIÓN */
#Presentacion {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  color: #292e44;
}

#Banner {
  width: 470px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 6em;
}
#Presentacion #Banner h4 {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
#Presentacion #Banner h2 {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
#Presentacion #Banner p {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.cont {
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.relav {
  position: relative;
}
#Presentacion .circulo:nth-child(1) {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -150px;
  left: -150px;
  background: #fdc801;
}
#Presentacion .row .cont .relav .circulo:nth-child(1) {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #fdc801;
}
#Presentacion .row .cont .relav .circulo:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #282747;
}

#home {
  min-width: 209px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header id="header">
  <nav
    class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light px-md-4 animated"
    id="navBar"
  >
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"
        ><img
          class="mr-2"
          src="../../../assets/bootstrap-solid.svg"
          width="30"
          height="30"
          alt="logotipo"
        />Juan Carlos</a
      >
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler navTrigger"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbar"
        aria-controls="navbar"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navTrigger"> <i></i><i></i><i></i> </span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse FondoDeLista" id="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Acerca de mí</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicios</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portafolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="" id="Presentacion">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="d-none d-md-block circulo"></div>
      <div class="col-12 BarraEnBlanco"></div>
      <div class="col-6 p-5">
        <div class="">
          <h4 class="">Hi There!</h4>
          <h2 class="">I'm Web Developer</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio
            explicabo est voluptates, nam nostrum quaerat tenetur, qui iste
            architecto adipisci saepe excepturi nisi. Ea dicta atque temporibus
            natus minima tempore.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 cont">
        <div class="relav">
          <div class="circulo"></div>
          <div class="circulo"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12" id="home">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<footer>
  <div class="container"></div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, por la aclaración.